# perl: add to a path using substitution

Tags: regex, perl, replace

My script takes in a filepath, and I want to append a directory to the end of the path. The issue is I want to be agnostic of whether the argument has a trailing slash or not.  So for example:

```
$ perl myscript.pl /path/to/dir
/path/to/dir/new
$ perl myscript.pl /path/to/dir/
/path/to/dir/new
```

I tried `$path =~ s/\/?$/\/new/g`, but that results in a double `/new` if a slash is present:

```
$ perl myscript.pl /path/to/dir
/path/to/dir/new/new
$ perl myscript.pl /path/to/dir
/path/to/dir/new
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the `/g` modifier:

```
$path =~ s/\/?$/\/new/
```

works fine.
You only want to modify add one "new" at the end, so having a `/g` modifier makes no sense.

---

Also, note that you can use different delimiters for your regex:

```
$path =~ s{ /? $}{/new}x;
```

is a little bit clearer.

Comment: thanks. That worked. Can you explain what was happening?

Comment: `$` doesn't consume the "end of string", it's merely an assertion (it asserts that "the end of the string is here"). So with `/?`, your regex matches at two positions: first it matches the `/` followed by the end of line, and then if matches *nothing* followed by the end of line. Is that clear?

Comment: Sort of, but why does that not result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Because the regex can't match twice at the same position: it matches once before the `/` and once after. Hence the two `/new`

Comment: ok I think I get it now: the regex iterates over the original string one character at a time. if it finds a match, it replaces the text, then continues in the original string from the next character after the replaced text. That right?

Comment: Yep, that's the general idea.

Answer (score 2):

Because `/g` is 'global' and will match multiple times:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#turn on debugging
use re 'debug';

my $path = '/path/to/dir/';
$path =~ s/\/?$/\/new/g;

print $path;
```

After the first replacement, the regex engine has 'left' the "end of line" marker, and doesn't need to match the optional `/`. So matches a second time.

E.g.:

```
Compiling REx "/?$"
Final program:
   1: CURLY {0,1} (5)
   3:   EXACT </> (0)
   5: SEOL (6)
   6: END (0)
floating ""$ at 0..1 (checking floating) minlen 0 
Matching REx "/?$" against "/path/to/dir/"
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [0..13] gave 13
  Found floating substr ""$ at offset 13 (rx_origin now 12)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
  try at offset...
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 12
  12 <path/to/dir> </>       |  1:CURLY {0,1}(5)
                                  EXACT </> can match 1 times out of 1...
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  5:  SEOL(6)
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  6:  END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "/?$" against ""
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [13..13] gave 13
  Found floating substr ""$ at offset 13 (rx_origin now 13)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 13
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  1:CURLY {0,1}(5)
                                  EXACT </> can match 0 times out of 1...
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  5:  SEOL(6)
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  6:  END(0)
Match successful!
Matching REx "/?$" against ""
Intuit: trying to determine minimum start position...
  doing 'check' fbm scan, [13..13] gave 13
  Found floating substr ""$ at offset 13 (rx_origin now 13)...
  (multiline anchor test skipped)
Intuit: Successfully guessed: match at offset 13
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  1:CURLY {0,1}(5)
                                  EXACT </> can match 0 times out of 1...
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  5:  SEOL(6)
  13 <path/to/dir/> <>       |  6:  END(0)
```

This is because `$` is a zero width position anchor. And so is `\/?` if there's no matches. Once the pattern has been consumed all the way up to the trailing `/` and replaced.. then the regex engine continues (because you told it to with `/g`) and find just `$` left, because that's still the end of line. And that's still a valid match to replace.

But why not instead use [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use Data::Dumper;

my $path = '/path/to/dir/';

my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir($path);

print Dumper \@dirs;

$path = File::Spec->catdir(@dirs, "new" );
print $path;
```

This provides you with a platform independent way to split and join path elements, and doesn't rely on regex matching - which there's various ways it could break (such as the one you found).

Comment: `After the first replacement, the regex engine has 'left' the "end of line" marker, and doesn't need to match the optional /`. I don't follow. If it continues to match after the replace, why does this not result in an infinite loop?

Comment: If you run the above, you'll see what the regex is doing. It's because `$` is zero width, as is an empty string (`\/?`). So once it does the first replace - the regex tries again, from the same start location - it has already 'consumed' the `/` by the previous match, but it doesn't need it in order to match just `$`.